# C# 4 event race condition

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a winform application. my winforms will register an event from a manager class. could a race condition happen here when the event (triggered by a work thread, e.g. by a tcp connection) is invoking all the event handlers, and at the same time a registered winform has closed?

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it, I don't think there's a place for a race condition, as long as all events are sourced and handled on the same main UI thread.

The form might get closed and even disposed of between invocation of two separate event handlers for the same event, but I wouldn't call it a race condition.

**Updated to follow the changed question.** If the event is triggered from a worker thread, all registered handlers will be called on that thread too. Meanwhile, the form can get closed. Note that may effectively exit your process and terminate the worker thread (when the main UI thread's `Application.Run` exits, this is controlled by `Thread.IsBackground` on the worker thread).

There is also a lot of opportunities for deadlocks and race conditions, depending on what you're actually doing inside your event handlers and how you communicate to the form itself (e.g., `control.Invoke` or `control.BeginInvoke`).

Answer (score 0):

If any of your forms subscribes to `SomeManager.SomeEvent`, than `SomeManager` instance (or `SomeManager` type, if the event is static) holds a reference to the form, and the form can't be collected by GC.

When event will be fired, event handler, which resides in form, will be executed. It doesn't matter, if the form is closed at this moment. Also, it doesn't matter, which thread executes event handlers.

There's nothing about race condition here, but you should note, that handler could be invoked after the form is closed. IMO, the right way is to unsubscribe from the event before closing the form.

Comment: o yes, the reference would not be collect by GC. so should i check this is closed from the event handler?

Comment: @BryanFok: I think, the right way is to unsubscribe from the event **before** closing the form.

Comment: yes, i shouldn't use the term race condition, i should use the term thread safety, but thats what many people else call this problem...

Comment: But what if I unsubscribed the event in the winform and then winform closed while the event is still executing? Than the closed form's event handler will have to check itself is closed or not to decided update the form control presentation or not. In this case, additional code to check the current form state is still needed, am i right?

Comment: @BryanFok: no, you have to add some synchronization code. If event handler executing, you shouldn't close the form until event handler doesn't return. If the form closing, you shouldn't execute handler.